# Entering U.K. with expired passport but valid BRP and valid passport of other nationality

Tags: visas, uk, passports, us-citizens, peruvian-citizens

So I am returning from a trip to Germany to the U.K. on September 10, but my Peruvian passport expires on September 7. My biometric residence permit is valid through the next three years, but because my passport is expired will I be refused entry? I am in the process of renewing my passport, but it is impossible to have it ready on time. However, I do have a valid passport under my American nationality. Would it be possible for the officer to stamp that instead or let me in anyway. I cannot cancel this trip, so if anyone has any solutions to helping me figure out solutions that will be very helpful. I plan to use the American passport to register with the airline so it will not be a problem for them to allow me to board my only issue is entering the U.K. again.

Comment: I don't have any authoritative sources to hand, but if I were going to do this, I'd travel both directions on the US passport. My feeling on this is it will probably be OK; after all, you are the resident, not your passport.

Answer (score 1):

Your BRP is evidence of your immigration status in the UK https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits You will have to show it along with your valid national passport before you begin your return journey, and again when you re-enter the United Kingdom. The permit proves that you are allowed to return to the United Kingdom, but it cannot be used instead of a passport.

Since your US passport is valid, it is sufficient alongside your BRP.